# dagger android support proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard, dagger-2, android-proguard, dagger

I'm using **Dagger2 android-support** library with **Proguard** but i can't compile my project because of this error :

```
Warning:dagger.android.AndroidInjector: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.DoNotMock
Warning:dagger.android.AndroidInjector$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.DoNotMock
Warning:dagger.android.AndroidInjector$Factory: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.DoNotMock
Warning:dagger.android.DaggerApplication: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.ForOverride
Warning:dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector: can't find referenced class com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
Warning:there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

The version of Dagger that I'm using is [2.11](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.dagger%7Cdagger%7C2.11%7C).

The question is what Proguard rules should i use for Dagger2 android-support library ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Should be:

```
-keep class com.google.errorprone.annotations.** { *; }
```

**Update**: Probably the following rule alone is enough, no need to add previous rule.

```
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, -dontwarn rule worked fine but the other one didn't worked